# Plentymarkets - backend plugin routes

Tags: php, angular

I have an angular backend plugin for Plentymarktes in which I need to access isPaid method form MarketplacePurchaseInformationContract.
(
https://developers.plentymarkets.com/en-gb/interface/stable7/PlentyMarketplace.html from it.)

The problem is that there is no way to access it directly from angular.

The idea is to create a PHP service that will get the data from contract and provide a route for angular to access (via REST GET).
(If you know a better/different way let me know ;))

Since my php knowledge is rusty at best I've taken a simple example and trying to figure it out.

```
class HelloWorldRouteServiceProvider extends RouteServiceProvider
{
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->get('hello', 'Controllers\ContentController@sayHello');
    }
}
```

Do I understand it correct that it binds the route 'hello' to 'sayHello' function in ContentController ?
So I should be able to do GET '[pluginRoute]/hello' ?

(Currently I am getting 403 on all possible  variations of that route so I am backing out to figure out if I even understand the route mapping in php correcly)

Comment: Wich php-framework is this?

Comment: If you're asking about RouteServciceProvider  it is their custom: Plenty\Plugin\RouteServiceProvider,  PHP 7.0